# How can I build a Manipulate expression to interactively solve an equation with many parameters?

Tags: equation-solving, manipulate

I'm new to Mathematica and I'm a little lost as to how to do this.

I have a somewhat complicated equation with a bunch of different input variables and one output variable (pco2) and I want to create a manipulate output for the variable pco2.

```
equation = 
  (-0.4692*cprop+1.4919)*(pco2-tc)+(so+a/(po2-po))*(pco2-tp)+dw == 
  k*vco2/(pco2*(1-vdanat-vdalvratio))-(psv-vth*r-peepi)*fr/(1/cl + 1/ccw);
```

I turned this into a function as such:

```
fpco2[
  r_, dw_, a_, fr_, po_, tc_, tp_, cprop_, po2_, peepi_, so_, vth_, psv_, cl_, 
  ccw_, k_, vco2_, vdanat_, vdalvratio_] := 
  Evaluate[equation];
```

I want be able to be able to create a Manipulate expression which can tell me the values of the variable pco2 for different inputs. So I tried:

```
Pane[
  Manipulate[
    Column[
      {
        Pane[
          {"Test=", 
           fpco2[r, dw, a, fr, po, tc, tp, cprop, po2, peepi, so, vth, psv, 
                 cl, ccw, k, vco2, vdanat, vdalvratio]}]}],
    {{cl,0.075,"CL"},0,2,Appearance->"Labeled"},
    {{ccw,0.125,"CCW"},0,2.5,Appearance->"Labeled"},
    {{r,5,"R"},0,10,Appearance->"Labeled"},
    {{peepi,0,"PEEPi"},0,20,Appearance->"Labeled"}, 
    {{po2,100,"PO2"},60,140,Appearance->"Labeled"}, 
    {{vth,0.2,"VTH"},0,1,Appearance->"Labeled"}, 
    {{psv,0,"PSV"},0,15,Appearance->"Labeled"}, 
    {{cprop,0.5,"CPROP"},0,3,Appearance->"Labeled"}, 
    {{dw,7,"DW"},0,15,Appearance->"Labeled"}, 
    {{a,16.7,"A"},0,20,Appearance->"Labeled"},
    {{fr,20,"FR"},0,30,Appearance->"Labeled"},
    {{po,30,"PO"},0,50,Appearance->"Labeled"},
    {{tc,34,"TC"},0,50,Appearance->"Labeled"},
    {{tp,34,"TP"},0,50,Appearance->"Labeled"},
    {{so,0,"SO"},0,2,Appearance->"Labeled"},
    {{k,0.75,"K"},0,5,Appearance->"Labeled"},
    {{vco2,0.25,"VCO2"},0,3,Appearance->"Labeled"},
    {{vdanat,0.12,"VDANAT"},0,1,Appearance->"Labeled"},
    {{vdalvratio,0.3,"VDALV"},0,1,Appearance->"Labeled"},
    ContentSize->Automatic]]
```

and this gets me:

[image]

which doesn't end up returning just the pco2 value but an expression for pco2.

When I try a sample input to my function:

```
fpco2[5,7,16.7,20,30,34,34,0.5,100,0,0,0.2,10,0.075,0.125,0.75,0.25,0.12,0.3]
```

I get

> ```
> 7 + 1.49587 (-34 + pco2) == -8.4375 + 0.323276/pco2
> ```

which only becomes the answer I want when I apply NSolve onto it:

```
NSolve[fpco2[5,7,16.7,20,30,34,34,0.5,100,0,0,0.2,10,0.075,0.125,0.75,0.25,0.12,0.3],pco2]
```

> ```
> {{pco2 -> 23.6891}, {pco2 -> -0.00912287}}
> ```

Anyone know how I can get my desired output?

Comment: Sorry - I copied a wrong bit of code as I was playing around with it. I mean to put in my function there not the variable 'solution'.

Comment: You've realized the problem yourself, no?  You've created one equation with one unknown variable.  Mathematica won't solve it until you ask it to, using `Solve` or `NSolve`.  Just do `Row@{"Test=", Solve[ fpco2[ ... ], pco2 ]`.  (`Row` is just for formatting.)  Note that you can probably solve the symbolic equation before plugging in values, which will make `Manipulate` run even faster.

Comment: Ah thanks a bunch. I feel a little silly now.

Comment: @Regailia No worries -- happens to all of us!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this might be what you want or, at least, it will get moving in the right direction.

I have modified your `Manipulate` expression in the following ways:

- Corrected some syntax errors.
- Removed unneeded code, including the definition of function `fpco2`.
- Wrapped the expression in `Block` to make sure certain free variables remain value free.
- Introduced `Row` to improve output formatting.
- Solved the equation within the expression.

```
Block[{eq, sol, pco2},
  Manipulate[
    eq = 
      (-0.4692*cprop + 1.4919)*(pco2 - tc) + 
        (so + a/(po2 - po))*(pco2 - tp) + dw == 
      k*vco2/(pco2*(1 - vdanat - vdalvratio)) - 
        (psv - vth*r - peepi)*fr/(1/cl + 1/ccw);
    sol = NSolve[eq, pco2];
    Column[{Row[ {"Equation: ", eq}], Row[{"Solutions: ", sol}]}],
    {{cl, 0.075, "CL"}, 0, 2, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
    {{ccw, 0.125, "CCW"}, 0, 2.5, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
    {{r, 5, "R"}, 0, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
    {{peepi, 0, "PEEPi"}, 0, 20, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
    {{po2, 100, "PO2"}, 60, 140, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
    {{vth, 0.2, "VTH"}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
    {{psv, 0, "PSV"}, 0, 15, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
    {{cprop, 0.5, "CPROP"}, 0, 3, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
    {{dw, 7, "DW"}, 0, 15, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
    {{a, 16.7, "A"}, 0, 20, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
    {{fr, 20, "FR"}, 0, 30, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
    {{po, 30, "PO"}, 0, 50, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
    {{tc, 34, "TC"}, 0, 50, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
    {{tp, 34, "TP"}, 0, 50, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
    {{so, 0, "SO"}, 0, 2, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
    {{k, 0.75, "K"}, 0, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
    {{vco2, 0.25, "VCO2"}, 0, 3, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
    {{vdanat, 0.12, "VDANAT"}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
    {{vdalvratio, 0.3, "VDALV"}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  ControlPlacement -> Bottom]]
```

[image: demo]